# c3 timeseries graph - how to have X values with no initial Y values

Tags: javascript, c3.js

I have a [C3 timeseries chart](http://c3js.org) where I wish to display a bunch if times every 15 minutes for a day, so that the day takes up the whole X axis and then just display data as the day progresses and the data comes in.

I have the following setup..

```
var now = new Date().toISOString();

  this.lineChart = generate({
    bindto: '#line',
    transition: {
      duration: 1000
    },        
    data: {
      x: 'x',
      xFormat: '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%LZ',
       columns: [
      ['x', now], 
      ['data1', 0]                   
    ]
    },
    axis: {
      x: {
        type: 'timeseries',
        localtime: true,
        tick: {
          format: '%H:%M %p',
          culling : true,
          rotate : 60
        }
      }
    }
  });
```

An d I then load the dates as follows..

```
let shiftStart = new Date(startDateTime);
  let endTime = new Date(endDateTime);
  let nextDate = shiftStart;
  let dates = new Array<string>();
  dates.push(nextDate.toISOString());
  let data = [];
  while (nextDate <= endTime) {
    nextDate = moment(nextDate).add(30, 'm').toDate();
    dates.push(nextDate.toISOString());
    data.push(0); // to make them show up!
  }

  this.lineChart.load({
    columns: [
      ['x', ...dates],
      ['myData', ...data]          
    ]
  })
```

It seems I have to add the `data` above to have the ticks show up for the times.

I would like to have ..

```
while (nextDate <= endTime) {
    nextDate = moment(nextDate).add(30, 'm').toDate();
    dates.push(nextDate.toISOString());
  }

  this.lineChart.load({
    columns: [
      ['x', ...dates],
    ]
  })
```

and for this to show just the X axis of times, and no values for the Y axis (yet)

Is this possible?

Any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, you can just use NaN for the value to get what I was after...

[image]

Now just to work out those uneven ticks, and truncated last tick value...